# Connect to wifi w/out DE and DM

Tags: wifi, network-interface, connectivity

When installing LAMP server, I went for tasksel, and got my DE (Xfce) and seemingly also display manager (LightDM) removed (this is [a](https://bugs.launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/tasksel/+bug/1338223) known ["bug"](https://bugs.launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/tasksel/+bug/574287), believe [it](https://bugs.launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/tasksel/+bug/1779645) or not). Now I just need to connect to wifi to start [reinstalling](https://forums.linuxmint.com/viewtopic.php?p=717605&sid=0b0e050bca946f8db3eb63286bc2f5cb#p717605) the removed components.

However, it seems there's very little to start with. I have no wireless interface (`ifconfig -a` shows only `enp0s` and `lo`). I have no `nmcli`, `iw`, `iwconfig`, `iwlist`, `wpa_supplicant`, `ifup` or `ifdown`. By way of relevant tools, I have at least (and maybe only) `ip`, `dhclient`, `netplan` and `ifconfig`. `systemctl status network-manager` shows that `network-manager.service` is loaded and inactive (dead). I can activate it w/ `systemctl restart network-manager`, but that's it. I edited /etc/network/interfaces, to include the wireless info, as described [here](https://askubuntu.com/questions/652401/i-accidentally-deleted-the-network-manager-and-dont-have-access-to-internet-any/652419#652419), and rebooted. This bought me nothing. `lspci -v` assures me I (still) have Intel Wireless 8265 / 8275 network controller. The question: Is there anything I could try to do to connect to wifi other than a complete reinstall of the distro? Something to get things going. I'm on Ubuntu 18.04 LTS

Comment: I am not super familiar with the exact names of the packages on Ubuntu but it seems you you know what you need already you can download those packages directly from https://packages.ubuntu.com/ then manually install them with sudo apt install /path/to/package

Comment: @JasonCroyle I could e.g. try to install `network-manager` (confusingly, I have the service but not the package installed), which would give me `nmcli` (+ `iw`, `modemmanager` and `wpa_supplicant` as its dependencies). This would mean downloading ca. 30 dependencies, many of which have dependencies, some of which have dependencies, etc., all of which have to be downloaded. It's feasible, but reinstalling a distro is probably easier

Comment: Your probably correct there I am assuming you have already checked that all the dependencies where removed also.  The only other idea I have would be booting from a live usb and then chroot into the install and repair it that way.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The issue was solved w/ chroot (thanks to Jason Croyle for the tip). Perhaps "cheating" (as I made the wifi connection in another system), but an "honest" solution wasn't forthcoming. Luckily, I had another Linux installed on the computer, so didn't even have to use a live USB. The procedure itself is described [here](https://superuser.com/questions/111152/whats-the-proper-way-to-prepare-chroot-to-recover-a-broken-linux-installation/111215#111215). I also made a script, as suggested [here](https://superuser.com/questions/111152/whats-the-proper-way-to-prepare-chroot-to-recover-a-broken-linux-installation/111215#comment133206_111215) (actually two: one to chroot and the other for the cleanup after the chroot). With the script I got the "No tty present and no askpass.." error on `sudo chroot /mnt/sda8 /bin/bash`, solved by `sudo -S chroot /mnt/sda8 /bin/bash` (where `-S` explicitly asks for a password from stdin).

I could also comment on how to recover from the havoc wrecked by tasksel, but given SE's "laser-like focus", I probably shouldn't. So just do yourself a favor and avoid tasksel